# What are Perl built-in operators/functions?

Tags: perl

I'm reading *[Beginning Perl](http://learn.perl.org/books/beginning-perl/)* by Simon Cozens and in *Chapter 8 - Subroutines* he states that "subroutines" are user functions, while `print`, `open`, `split`, etc. are built-in operators or functions.

What are they? Are they really built-in, language-intrinsic features (like C's `sizeof` operator) or are they, actually, subroutines/functions of the `main` module?

If they're subroutines, are `while`, `for`, `unless`, etc. also subroutines? What about the operators like `+`, `-`, `eq`, etc.?

Comment: I'd look at `perldoc perlfunc` and `perldoc -f <function name>`.

Comment: This is my favorite list of perl operators: http://www.ozonehouse.com/mark/periodic/

Comment: @Seth That's for Perl 6, which (for all intents & purposes) is a completely separate language from Perl 5, which is what just about everyone means when they say "Perl."

Comment: @jwodder: Fair enough, but it's still my favorite!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`print`, `open`, `split` are not subroutines. They do not result in sub calls. They are not even present in the symbol table (in `main::` or otherwise, although you can refer to them as `CORE::split`, etc), and one cannot get a reference to their code (although work is being done to create proxy subs for them in `CORE::` for when you want to treat them as subroutines). They are operators just like `+`.

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'sub f {} f()'
1  <0> enter 
2  <;> nextstate(main 2 -e:1) v:{
3  <0> pushmark s
4  <#> gv[*f] s
5  <1> entersub[t3] vKS/TARG,1      <--- sub call
6  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC
-e syntax OK

$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'split /;/'
1  <0> enter 
2  <;> nextstate(main 1 -e:1) v:{
3  </> pushre(/";"/) s/64
4  <#> gvsv[*_] s
5  <$> const[IV 0] s
6  <@> split[t2] vK                 <--- not a sub call
7  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC
-e syntax OK

$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'$x + $y'
1  <0> enter 
2  <;> nextstate(main 1 -e:1) v:{
3  <#> gvsv[*x] s
4  <#> gvsv[*y] s
5  <2> add[t3] vK/2                 <--- Just like this
6  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC
-e syntax OK
```

They are known by a variety of names:

- builtin functions
- functions
- builtins
- named operators

And most are considered to be one of the following:

- list operator
- named unary operator

Subroutines are often called functions (as they are in C and C++), so "function" is an ambiguous word. This ambiguity appears to be the basis of your question.

---

As for `while`, `for`, `unless`, etc, they are keywords used by *flow control statements*

```
while (f()) { g() }
```

and *statement modifiers*

```
g() while f();
```

Comment: Is the code you've posted the code that Perl's VM understands, generated by the perl interpreter?

Comment: @Raphael, Yes, They are representations of the opcode trees that result from compiling the programs.

Answer (score 11):

The Perl keywords are those defined in the `regen/keywords.pl` file within the Perl source distribution.  These are:

> __FILE__, __LINE__, __PACKAGE__, __DATA__, __END__, AUTOLOAD, BEGIN,
>   UNITCHECK, CORE, DESTROY, END, INIT, CHECK, abs, accept, alarm,
>   and, atan2, bind, binmode, bless, break, caller, chdir, chmod,
>   chomp, chop, chown, chr, chroot, close, closedir, cmp, connect,
>   continue, cos, crypt, dbmclose, dbmopen, default, defined, delete,
>   die, do, dump, each, else, elsif, endgrent, endhostent, endnetent,
>   endprotoent, endpwent, endservent, eof, eq, eval, exec, exists,
>   exit, exp, fcntl, fileno, flock, for, foreach, fork, format, formline,
>   ge, getc, getgrent, getgrgid, getgrnam, gethostbyaddr, gethostbyname,
>   gethostent, getlogin, getnetbyaddr, getnetbyname, getnetent,
>   getpeername, getpgrp, getppid, getpriority, getprotobyname,
>   getprotobynumber, getprotoent, getpwent, getpwnam, getpwuid,
>   getservbyname, getservbyport, getservent, getsockname, getsockopt,
>   given, glob, gmtime, goto, grep, gt, hex, if, index, int, ioctl,
>   join, keys, kill, last, lc, lcfirst, le, length, link, listen,
>   local, localtime, lock, log, lstat, lt, m, map, mkdir, msgctl,
>   msgget, msgrcv, msgsnd, my, ne, next, no, not, oct, open, opendir,
>   or, ord, our, pack, package, pipe, pop, pos, print, printf, prototype,
>   push, q, qq, qr, quotemeta, qw, qx, rand, read, readdir, readline,
>   readlink, readpipe, recv, redo, ref, rename, require, reset, return,
>   reverse, rewinddir, rindex, rmdir, s, say, scalar, seek, seekdir,
>   select, semctl, semget, semop, send, setgrent, sethostent, setnetent,
>   setpgrp, setpriority, setprotoent, setpwent, setservent, setsockopt,
>   shift, shmctl, shmget, shmread, shmwrite, shutdown, sin, sleep,
>   socket, socketpair, sort, splice, split, sprintf, sqrt, srand, stat,
>   state, study, sub, substr, symlink, syscall, sysopen, sysread,
>   sysseek, system, syswrite, tell, telldir, tie, tied, time, times,
>   tr, truncate, uc, ucfirst, umask, undef, unless, unlink, unpack,
>   unshift, untie, until, use, utime, values, vec, wait, waitpid,
>   wantarray, warn, when, while, write, x, xor, y.

The *perlsyn*, *perlop*, and *perlsub* manpages are required reading, followed perhaps by the *perlfunc* manpage.   To learn how to override builtin operators used with objects, see the *overload* manpage.

Comment: Never saw a language with that much keywords!

Comment: @Raphael: Then don't look at COBOL. ;)

Comment: @Raphael: You probably are thinking of keywords as something that cannot be overridden, like `if` and `unless`.  **Perl has *very few* of those absolutely inviolate keywords.** Most of Perl’s keywords from `regen/keywords.pl` can be indeed be overridden through one (or more) of three ways: by importing a function of that name from another package (as in `chdir` or `open`) or else through either tying (as in `keys` or `pop`) or operator overloading (as in `print`, `cmp`, or `qq`). Which is which requires experience with the language to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in operators are not Perl subroutines.  For example,

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub Foo { print "In foo\n"; }

my $ref;

$ref = \&Foo;
$ref->();

$ref = \&print;
$ref->();
```

The first `$ref->();` is an indirect call; it prints "In foo".

The second one produces a warning:

```
Undefined subroutine &main::print called at ./tmp.pl line 14
```

because `print` is not the name of a subroutine.

Comment: fyi, `\&CORE::builtin` is being added in 5.16. It'll autovivify a sub that calls the builtin.

Answer (score 0):

Simply think of "built-in functions" as functions that you did not create. Easy right? :-)

Comment: Except you can't take a reference to them. Except you can't override their prototype and special parsing rules by prefixing the call with `&`. Except you can't `goto` them. (and I'm sure I'm missing some)