# in Perl, how to assign the print function to a variable?

Tags: perl, namespaces

I need to control the print method using a variable

My code is below

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# test_assign_func.pl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub echo {
   my ($string) = @_;
   print "from echo: $string\n\n";
}  

my $myprint = \&echo;
$myprint->("hello");

$myprint = \&print;
$myprint->("world");
```

when I ran, I got the following error for the assignment of print function

```
$ test_assign_func.pl
from echo: hello

Undefined subroutine &main::print called at test_assign_func.pl line 17.
```

Looks like I need to prefix a namespace to print function but I cannot find the name space. Thank you for any advice!

Comment: What possible reason could you have for doing this? Seems like an XY-problem.

Comment: @TLP and folks asking why I asked this question. I stumbled into this when I wrote so called high-order Perl programming, the Dispatcher Pattern. I had difficulty to dispatch to the print "function".  I simplified my program into the above code. Now I know print is not a function, neither a sub, nor a common operator.

Comment: related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153265/perl-built-in-functions-as-a-subroutine-reference?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`print` is an operator, not a sub.

perlfunc:

> The functions in this section can serve as terms in an expression. They fall into two major categories: list operators and named unary operators.

Perl provides a sub for named operators that can be duplicated by a sub with a prototype. A reference to these can be obtained using `\&CORE::name`.

```perl
my $f = \&CORE::length;
say $f->("abc");   # 3
```

But `print` isn't such an operator (because of the way it accepts a file handle). For these, you'll need to create a sub with a more limited calling convention.

```perl
my $f = sub { print @_ };
$f->("abc\n");
```

Related:

- [What are Perl built-in operators/functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7167599/589924)

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in [CORE](http://p3rl.org/CORE), some functions can't be called as subroutines, only as barewords. [print](http://p3rl.org/print) is one of them.